# Why am I getting "data source access error" when dataset can be refreshed?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, powerbi-desktop, impersonation

Using Powerbi Desktop, I published a dataset that I can now see at `https://app.powerbi.com/`. When I go to the dataset and click "Refresh Now" it does so successfully (no errors are displayed).

So why is it that if I click on "Create report" I get error "There was a data source access error. Please contact the gateway administrator."

[image]

So here's some background info on the credentialing. Maybe it will help.

Our server falls under domain `FirstCompany`, so I log on as `FirstCompany\Joe`. In SSDT, I create an SSAS cube and create a read-only role for `FirstCompany\Joe`. Then I deploy the cube.

At my workstation (which I also log in as `FirstCompany\Joe`), I open Powerbi Desktop and log in as `Joe@SecondCompany.com` because I have a Pro account. I create the powerbi document using the SSAS cube above. Once the *pbix* is ready, I publish it to app.powerbuilder.com (also under `Joe@SecondCompany.com`). I go to "My Workspace" and see the report and dataset. I can refresh the dataset successfully.

The issue here is that my Pro powerbi account is under the email `Joe@SecondCompany.com`, but the cube was created and published under domain `FirstCompany\Joe`. From what I've read, the email used to sign in to Power BI is then passed to Analysis Services as the effective user.

Is it possible for `Joe@SecondCompany.com` to access the cube that was created under `FirstCompany\Joe`?

I've already installed the `On-premises data gateway` in the server, and Since I can refresh my dataset at app.powerbi.com, that means that the gateway's working.

Also, when I click on "Test All Connections" I get *Online: You are good to go.*.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem too. I have reviewed the "Roles" of SSAS and I have deleted the roles that do not exist anymore.

Moreover, I exported the gateway error logs and in these logs, sentences that start with "InnerMessage" indicates the error. For example, error logs said some users do not have any access to the SSAS, so I gave role that users.

I hope it helps.